# How to Implement parallax scroll effect into flickerplate jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is driving me NUTS!
Right, I've downloaded flickerplate's slideshow script and it's working 100% but if you go to the their website to view their demo, [Click here](http://getwebplate.com/plugins/flickerplate) you'll see that it has a parallax scroll effect. Now I want to use that parallax scroll effect too but they don't include it with their download (I initially thought the parallax scroll effect came with the slideshow).

So I've been spending HOURS and HOURS trying to locate the source code for this parallax scroll effect and for the life of me, I cannot find it! What makes it difficult is that they minify all their code so it's almost hopeless for person like me who isn't a javascript guru.

So I've had to resort to trying out a third party parallax scroll script [Here](http://pixelcog.com/parallax.js/) and although I can get this script to work on a single image, I'm having no success implementing it into the flickerplate script (not surprisingly).

Here is the markup for the flickerplate script:

```
<div class="flicker-example" data-block-text="false">
    <ul>
        <li data-background="santa-maria-inhaca-island-mozambique-01.jpg"></li>
        <li data-background="nhoxani-lodge-santa-maria-mozambique.jpg"></li>
        <li data-background="santa-maria-accommodation-inhaca-island.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the Markup for a SINGLE image using the Parallax script:

```
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="braby-villa-self-catering.jpg">
</div>
```

So obviously the problem is that this markup is per image (per ONE image), so I tried using it with the list items in the flickerplate markup above but that doesn't work - the image / background disappears. I'm assuming there's some conflict. This is the problem when trying to use a third party plugin with another.

What would probably be a lot easier is if I could find the same parallax scroll script that flickerplate used in their demo page, but I can't get any information on it ... maybe you can? I just want it like their demo page.